# Does the PostgreSQL array inTOAST storage have random access times?

Tags: postgresql, array, complexity

This question is related to PostgreSQL TOAST storage and the GIS.SE question: [Should TOAST compression be disabled for PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/398337/should-toast-compression-be-disabled-for-postgis)

*Basically, I was wondering if there is any **guarantee** of constant time complexity (O(1)) for the random access of array elements?*

That is, to get `arr[n]`, is the worst case number of steps required a constant (i.e. `O(1)` ) or something else (`O(log n)` etc.)?

I am asking because in certain data forms such as PostGIS lines or rasters, the main data is logically an array (of coordinates). It is known that access time for such data can be extremely long once the data amount exceed a certain limit (like 500 points). A possible reason is that data of such sizes are transferred to TOAST storage and potentially the data can be compressed (e.g. with the `main` storage). It's not clear how PostgreSQL can predict the approximate location of an element and still offer random access time.

The access time for arrays in most programming languages is constant (`O(1)`). And that is the point of using an array. Just out of curiosity:

*Do PostgreSQL arrays have constant access times?* (when and when not?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the data type of the array elements.

If it is a fixed-width data type like `integer` or `uuid`, then the offset into the array can be calculated with a simple multiplication, and the complexity is O(1).

For variable-width data types like `text`, `varchar`, `char` or `jsonb`, each array element has different length, and accessing the n-th element in an array means skipping over the first n-1 elements, so the complecity is O(n).

See the function [`src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/arrayfuncs.c;h=660e854e93f4d06faeedc8cd39a85c3589796afc;hb=HEAD#l4644) in the source.

You can tell if a data type has fixed length by looking at the `typlen` column in `pg_type`. If that is -1, the type has variable length.

Comment: Thanks! For a fixed length type (e.g. `FLOAT8`), would TOAST compression and decompression interfere with the O(1) access; or is the storage mechanism a factor at all for accessing an array? Is the whole array always read into memory or is there some kind of *random access of the disk* for the chunks that may contain `arr[n]`?

Comment: The whole thing is read from disk into memory, no matter if it is toasted or not. I was just answering the question what the complexity for accessing the n-th element of an array is. The speed of loading the array from disk or de-toasting will be proportional to the array size, so that will also be O(n).

Comment: Large arrays are not a nice thing to have.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, since Postgres 13, leading bytes of TOAST values can be accessed due to this improvement. Quoting the [release notes of Postgres 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/release-13.html#id-1.11.6.9.5.3.5):

> Improve retrieval of the leading bytes of [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/storage-toast.html)'ed values (Binguo
> Bao, Andrey Borodin)
>
> Previously, compressed out-of-line TOAST values were fully fetched
> even when it's known that only some leading bytes are needed. Now,
> only enough data to produce the result is fetched.

This is the feature in question:

https://commitfest.postgresql.org/23/2135/

**But** it seems that cannot be applied to array access (yet). See Laurenz' comment.

Comment: Looking at commits 4d0e994eed83c845a05da6e9a417b4efec67efaf and 11a078cf87ffb611d19c7dec6df68b41084ad9c9, it seems like this is only used for `starts_with(text,text)` and `left(text,integer)`. After all, we cannot say in advance how much of the array we will need. I am sure this could be improved for arrays with a fixed-length element type, but it doesn't seem to have happened so far.

Comment: @Laurenz Thanks for clearing this up! There certainly seems to be potential for something like `array_col[1]` - when column statistics indicate long arrays ...